Angular MSAL, initialize for version 3
I am using
import { MsalModule } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

in an Angular 16 app for authentication against Azure/EntraID.
I bootstrap it in my app.modules.ts.
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [...
  ],
  imports: [
  ...
    


    MsalModule.forRoot (new PublicClientApplication ({
      auth: {
            
            clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      },
       cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
      }
    }), null, null)
  ],
  
  providers: [
            ...],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

Now after update from version 2 to version 3 of MsalModule there is the need of an additional call of PublicClientApplication.initialize () before the 1st use of it.
How can I do this in app.modules.ts and MsalModule.forRoot??
Or is it best practice to do this in a components OnInit?
